# How can I match on value and then add value to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Currently matching values from two different objects. When match is found, add value from one object to the other.

Recursively do this and return one new object.

I am a little lost. I have tried .map within .map and I have tried filter.

I will post the code below and any help will be massively appreciated. It is my last hurdle.

i want to match on either `location` or `postcode`
Then match the years.
Then add the `price` to the nested Object `year`

Here is my current function:

```
    findLocationYearAddPrice = () => {
        // console.log('compiledData', compiledData.map(i => i.location))
        // console.log('data', data.map(i => i.location))
        compiledData.map(i => {
            data.map(j => {
                if (i.location === j.location) {
                    Object.keys(i.year).filter(k => {
                        if (k === j.year) {
console.log('k', k)
                        }
                        return '';
                        //  console.log('undefined this', k)
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is the two sets (in brief) of data. The first set is where i want to match the year, then extract the price and add it to the better formed, more concise JSON of the second data Object.

below is `data` as referred to in the function

```
const data = [
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "91449",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50460",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barnet",
        "postcode": "EN5 5RP",
        "price": "93285",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bexley",
        "postcode": "DA16 3DN",
        "price": "64958",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Brent",
        "postcode": "HA9 9AA",
        "price": "71307",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bromley",
        "postcode": "BR1 3NN",
        "price": "81671",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Camden",
        "postcode": "NW1 8QL",
        "price": "120933",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Croydon",
        "postcode": "CR2 7PA",
        "price": "69158",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Ealing",
        "postcode": "W13 0JX",
        "price": "79886",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Enfield",
        "postcode": "EN2 7AA",
        "price": "72515",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Greenwich",
        "postcode": "SE9 1DU",
        "price": "62300",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hackney",
        "postcode": "E8 1FD",
        "price": "61297",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hammersmith & Fulham",
        "postcode": "W6 8AB",
        "price": "124903",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Haringey",
        "postcode": "N8 9DJ",
        "price": "76288",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Harrow",
        "postcode": "HA3 5AG",
        "price": "84770",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Havering",
        "postcode": "RM12 6PL",
        "price": "68000",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hillingdon",
        "postcode": "UB8 1JZ",
        "price": "73835",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hounslow",
        "postcode": "TW3 2DL",
        "price": "72232",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Islington",
        "postcode": "N5 1RA",
        "price": "92516",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Kensington & Chelsea",
        "postcode": "W8 5SA",
        "price": "182695",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Kingston upon Thames",
        "postcode": "KT5 9NX",
        "price": "80876",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Lambeth",
        "postcode": "SW9 8HE",
        "price": "67771",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Lewisham",
        "postcode": "SE6 4RE",
        "price": "60491",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Merton",
        "postcode": "SW20 9JT",
        "price": "82071",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Newham",
        "postcode": "E13 9AP",
        "price": "53539",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Redbridge",
        "postcode": "IG6 1NA",
        "price": "72190",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Richmond upon Thames",
        "postcode": "TW9 1EZ",
        "price": "109326",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Southwark",
        "postcode": "SE1 5AA",
        "price": "67885",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Sutton",
        "postcode": "SM1 1JA",
        "price": "71537",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Tower Hamlets",
        "postcode": "E14 7JE",
        "price": "59865",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Waltham Forest",
        "postcode": "E17 7LP",
        "price": "61319",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Wandsworth",
        "postcode": "SW12 8PB",
        "price": "88559",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Westminster",
        "postcode": "SW1H 0BB",
        "price": "133025,",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "108999",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50828",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barnet",
        "postcode": "EN5 5RP",
        "price": "91111",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bexley",
        "postcode": "DA16 3DN",
        "price": "63996",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Brent",
        "postcode": "HA9 9AA",
        "price": "72806",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bromley",
        "postcode": "BR1 3NN",
        "price": "82210",
        "year": "96"
    }
]
```

Second object that needs the data added too.

below is `compiledData` as referred to in the function

```
const compiledData = [
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "91449",
        "year": {
            "10": "",
            "11": "",
            "12": "",
            "13": "",
            "14": "",
            "15": "",
            "16": "",
            "17": "",
            "18": "",
            "19": "",
            "95": "",
            "96": "",
            "97": "",
            "98": "",
            "99": "",
            "00": "",
            "01": "",
            "02": "",
            "03": "",
            "04": "",
            "05": "",
            "06": "",
            "07": "",
            "08": "",
            "09": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50460",
        "year": {
            "10": "",
            "11": "",
            "12": "",
            "13": "",
            "14": "",
            "15": "",
            "16": "",
            "17": "",
            "18": "",
            "19": "",
            "95": "",
            "96": "",
            "97": "",
            "98": "",
            "99": "",
            "00": "",
            "01": "",
            "02": "",
            "03": "",
            "04": "",
            "05": "",
            "06": "",
            "07": "",
            "08": "",
            "09": ""
        }
    }
]
```

There is more data, but this is a concise version for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained my answer with comments in the code.

But to sumarize, you have to iterate within the `compiledData`, get the objects from `data` that matches the same `location`, then grab the year from these objects and fill the year that matches the year on the `compiledData`.

```
// iterate within the compiledData objects
compiledData.forEach(compiledDataObj => {
    // filter function return the objects that fulfil the requirements (if return is true, then the object is added, else not)
    const objectsWithSameLocation = data.filter(dataObj => {
        // return the objects with the same location only
        return dataObj.location === compiledDataObj.location
    });

    // iterate within the objects returned
    objectsWithSameLocation.forEach(obj => {
        // within the compiledDataObject, get the year parameter and fill the price that matched the same year
        compiledDataObj.year[obj.year] = obj.price
    });
});

console.log(compiledData);
```

Reduced syntax:

```
compiledData.forEach(compiledDataObj => {
    // filter function return the objects that fulfil the requirements (if return is true, then the object is added, else not)
    const objectsWithSameLocation = data.filter(dataObj => dataObj.location === compiledDataObj.location);

    // iterate within the objects returned
    objectsWithSameLocation.forEach(obj => compiledDataObj.year[obj.year] = obj.price);
});
```

Full code:

```
const data = [
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "91449",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50460",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barnet",
        "postcode": "EN5 5RP",
        "price": "93285",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bexley",
        "postcode": "DA16 3DN",
        "price": "64958",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Brent",
        "postcode": "HA9 9AA",
        "price": "71307",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bromley",
        "postcode": "BR1 3NN",
        "price": "81671",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Camden",
        "postcode": "NW1 8QL",
        "price": "120933",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Croydon",
        "postcode": "CR2 7PA",
        "price": "69158",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Ealing",
        "postcode": "W13 0JX",
        "price": "79886",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Enfield",
        "postcode": "EN2 7AA",
        "price": "72515",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Greenwich",
        "postcode": "SE9 1DU",
        "price": "62300",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hackney",
        "postcode": "E8 1FD",
        "price": "61297",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hammersmith & Fulham",
        "postcode": "W6 8AB",
        "price": "124903",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Haringey",
        "postcode": "N8 9DJ",
        "price": "76288",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Harrow",
        "postcode": "HA3 5AG",
        "price": "84770",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Havering",
        "postcode": "RM12 6PL",
        "price": "68000",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hillingdon",
        "postcode": "UB8 1JZ",
        "price": "73835",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Hounslow",
        "postcode": "TW3 2DL",
        "price": "72232",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Islington",
        "postcode": "N5 1RA",
        "price": "92516",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Kensington & Chelsea",
        "postcode": "W8 5SA",
        "price": "182695",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Kingston upon Thames",
        "postcode": "KT5 9NX",
        "price": "80876",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Lambeth",
        "postcode": "SW9 8HE",
        "price": "67771",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Lewisham",
        "postcode": "SE6 4RE",
        "price": "60491",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Merton",
        "postcode": "SW20 9JT",
        "price": "82071",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Newham",
        "postcode": "E13 9AP",
        "price": "53539",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Redbridge",
        "postcode": "IG6 1NA",
        "price": "72190",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Richmond upon Thames",
        "postcode": "TW9 1EZ",
        "price": "109326",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Southwark",
        "postcode": "SE1 5AA",
        "price": "67885",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Sutton",
        "postcode": "SM1 1JA",
        "price": "71537",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Tower Hamlets",
        "postcode": "E14 7JE",
        "price": "59865",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Waltham Forest",
        "postcode": "E17 7LP",
        "price": "61319",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Wandsworth",
        "postcode": "SW12 8PB",
        "price": "88559",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "Westminster",
        "postcode": "SW1H 0BB",
        "price": "133025,",
        "year": "95"
    },
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "108999",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50828",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Barnet",
        "postcode": "EN5 5RP",
        "price": "91111",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bexley",
        "postcode": "DA16 3DN",
        "price": "63996",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Brent",
        "postcode": "HA9 9AA",
        "price": "72806",
        "year": "96"
    },
    {
        "location": "Bromley",
        "postcode": "BR1 3NN",
        "price": "82210",
        "year": "96"
    }
];

const compiledData = [
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "price": "91449",
        "year": {
            "10": "",
            "11": "",
            "12": "",
            "13": "",
            "14": "",
            "15": "",
            "16": "",
            "17": "",
            "18": "",
            "19": "",
            "95": "",
            "96": "",
            "97": "",
            "98": "",
            "99": "",
            "00": "",
            "01": "",
            "02": "",
            "03": "",
            "04": "",
            "05": "",
            "06": "",
            "07": "",
            "08": "",
            "09": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "price": "50460",
        "year": {
            "10": "",
            "11": "",
            "12": "",
            "13": "",
            "14": "",
            "15": "",
            "16": "",
            "17": "",
            "18": "",
            "19": "",
            "95": "",
            "96": "",
            "97": "",
            "98": "",
            "99": "",
            "00": "",
            "01": "",
            "02": "",
            "03": "",
            "04": "",
            "05": "",
            "06": "",
            "07": "",
            "08": "",
            "09": ""
        }
    }
];

// iterate within the compiledData objects
compiledData.forEach(compiledDataObj => {
    // filter function return the objects that fulfil the requirements (if return is true, then the object is added, else not)
    const objectsWithSameLocation = data.filter(dataObj => {
        // return the objects with the same location only
        return dataObj.location === compiledDataObj.location
    });

    // iterate within the objects returned
    objectsWithSameLocation.forEach(obj => {
        // within the compiledDataObject, get the year parameter and fill the price that matched the same year
        compiledDataObj.year[obj.year] = obj.price
    });
});

console.log(compiledData);
```

Comment: I used your answer. It was the best explained, easiest to read and followed the patten i was using.

I confused my use of .filter and .reduce. Plus i could not find the year/how to add in the year & price

Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following code snippet. It may help you.
I took the raw array as complex (variable name) and iterating through it and storing the values in new field called as filtered.

```js
const complex = [{"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "91449", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50460", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "93285", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "64958", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "71307", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "81671", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Camden", "postcode": "NW1 8QL", "price": "120933", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Croydon", "postcode": "CR2 7PA", "price": "69158", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Ealing", "postcode": "W13 0JX", "price": "79886", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Enfield", "postcode": "EN2 7AA", "price": "72515", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Greenwich", "postcode": "SE9 1DU", "price": "62300", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hackney", "postcode": "E8 1FD", "price": "61297", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hammersmith & Fulham", "postcode": "W6 8AB", "price": "124903", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Haringey", "postcode": "N8 9DJ", "price": "76288", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Harrow", "postcode": "HA3 5AG", "price": "84770", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Havering", "postcode": "RM12 6PL", "price": "68000", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hillingdon", "postcode": "UB8 1JZ", "price": "73835", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hounslow", "postcode": "TW3 2DL", "price": "72232", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Islington", "postcode": "N5 1RA", "price": "92516", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kensington & Chelsea", "postcode": "W8 5SA", "price": "182695", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kingston upon Thames", "postcode": "KT5 9NX", "price": "80876", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lambeth", "postcode": "SW9 8HE", "price": "67771", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lewisham", "postcode": "SE6 4RE", "price": "60491", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Merton", "postcode": "SW20 9JT", "price": "82071", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Newham", "postcode": "E13 9AP", "price": "53539", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Redbridge", "postcode": "IG6 1NA", "price": "72190", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Richmond upon Thames", "postcode": "TW9 1EZ", "price": "109326", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Southwark", "postcode": "SE1 5AA", "price": "67885", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Sutton", "postcode": "SM1 1JA", "price": "71537", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Tower Hamlets", "postcode": "E14 7JE", "price": "59865", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Waltham Forest", "postcode": "E17 7LP", "price": "61319", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Wandsworth", "postcode": "SW12 8PB", "price": "88559", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Westminster", "postcode": "SW1H 0BB", "price": "133025", "year": "95"}, {"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "108999", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50828", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "91111", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "63996", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "72806", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "82210", "year": "96"}];

const filtered = [];    

complex.forEach( com => {
    if(filtered.length > 0 && filtered.filter( t => com.location === t.location).length > 0) {
        const index = filtered.findIndex( tt => tt.location === com.location);
        filtered[index]['year'][`${com['year']}`] = com['price']
    } else {
        let obj = {...com}
        obj['year'] = {[`${com['year']}`]: com['price']}
        filtered.push(obj);
    }
})
        
console.log(filtered);
```

Please refer the following for the response (In Json form)

```
{
    "location": "City of London",
    "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
    "price": "91449",
    "year": {
        "95": "91449",
        "96": "108999"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not a `reduce` rather than using a `forEach` to update a global variable?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thats the great suggestion. We  should use reduce, but foreach makes it to understand easily.

Comment: I agree, using ES6 methods makes a lot more sense. 

foreach does show us better, but they are realistically entirely different methods. They share qualities but do not behave the same. To change the original codes methods for different methods is going to cause misinformation and misdirection for learning.

Comment: Sorry Scott, sounds like I'm bashing you. I'm only commenting in a professional capacity, on a personal note your input is greatly appreciated and these kinds of discussions is why stackoverflow is stupendous.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a copy of filtered array to find the locations from `compiledData` in data, used redice to assign `year` and calculate price properties, removed existing entries in `data` and push new reduced element:

```js
var data = [{ "location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "91449", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50460", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "93285", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "64958", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "71307", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "81671", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Camden", "postcode": "NW1 8QL", "price": "120933", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Croydon", "postcode": "CR2 7PA", "price": "69158", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Ealing", "postcode": "W13 0JX", "price": "79886", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Enfield", "postcode": "EN2 7AA", "price": "72515", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Greenwich", "postcode": "SE9 1DU", "price": "62300", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Hackney", "postcode": "E8 1FD", "price": "61297", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Hammersmith & Fulham", "postcode": "W6 8AB", "price": "124903", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Haringey", "postcode": "N8 9DJ", "price": "76288", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Harrow", "postcode": "HA3 5AG", "price": "84770", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Havering", "postcode": "RM12 6PL", "price": "68000", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Hillingdon", "postcode": "UB8 1JZ", "price": "73835", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Hounslow", "postcode": "TW3 2DL", "price": "72232", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Islington", "postcode": "N5 1RA", "price": "92516", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Kensington & Chelsea", "postcode": "W8 5SA", "price": "182695", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Kingston upon Thames", "postcode": "KT5 9NX", "price": "80876", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Lambeth", "postcode": "SW9 8HE", "price": "67771", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Lewisham", "postcode": "SE6 4RE", "price": "60491", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Merton", "postcode": "SW20 9JT", "price": "82071", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Newham", "postcode": "E13 9AP", "price": "53539", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Redbridge", "postcode": "IG6 1NA", "price": "72190", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Richmond upon Thames", "postcode": "TW9 1EZ", "price": "109326", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Southwark", "postcode": "SE1 5AA", "price": "67885", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Sutton", "postcode": "SM1 1JA", "price": "71537", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Tower Hamlets", "postcode": "E14 7JE", "price": "59865", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Waltham Forest", "postcode": "E17 7LP", "price": "61319", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Wandsworth", "postcode": "SW12 8PB", "price": "88559", "year": "95" }, { "location": "Westminster", "postcode": "SW1H 0BB", "price": "133025,", "year": "95" }, { "location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "108999", "year": "96" }, { "location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50828", "year": "96" }, { "location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "91111", "year": "96" }, { "location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "63996", "year": "96" }, { "location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "72806", "year": "96" }, { "location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "82210", "year": "96" }
];
var compiledData = [{ "location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "91449", "year": { "10": "", "11": "", "12": "", "13": "", "14": "", "15": "", "16": "", "17": "", "18": "", "19": "", "95": "", "96": "", "97": "", "98": "", "99": "", "00": "", "01": "", "02": "", "03": "", "04": "", "05": "", "06": "", "07": "", "08": "", "09": "" } }, { "location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50460", "year": { "10": "", "11": "", "12": "", "13": "", "14": "", "15": "", "16": "", "17": "", "18": "", "19": "", "95": "", "96": "", "97": "", "98": "", "99": "", "00": "", "01": "", "02": "", "03": "", "04": "", "05": "", "06": "", "07": "", "08": "", "09": "" } }
];
compiledData.forEach(a => {
  var s = data.map(b => (b.location == a.location && Object.assign({}, b))).filter(item => !!item);
  s.push(a);
  s.reduce((acc, { price, year, ...obj }) => (acc.year = a.year, acc.price = Number(acc.price) + Number(price), acc));
  data.slice().forEach((x, i) => {
    if (x.location == a.location)
      data.splice(i, 1);
  });
  data.push(s[0]);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why have  you not used ES6 variable names when the question shows the use of these (e.g. var)?

Comment: Sorry force of habit, I’ll try to keep that in mind

Comment: It's fine to use var, but it could lead people astray (impressionable n00bs like me)

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from Gustavo Lopes, i used his code to help build this.

```
    findLocationYearAddPrice = () => {
            compiledData.map(compiledDataObj => {
                const objectsWithSameLocation = data.filter(dataObj => {
                    return  dataObj.location === compiledDataObj.location
                });
                objectsWithSameLocation.map(obj => {
                    compiledDataObj.year[obj.year] = obj.price
                })
            });
        };
```

It was the simplest to read and understand due to his comments and it kept true to how I was trying to achieve this. Plus the comments helped me achieve what I required.

I did convert it to ES6 due to the improved speed and return rate from es6 methods.

Answer (score 1):

As with most of the other answers here, I find that it makes more sense to build your target object from scratch.  Perhaps that won't work for you, and then this answer won't help.  But it does show a fairly useful technique.

The other thing to note is that it does not include the `price` at the top level of the objects in the output array.  I can't see that it makes any sense to include that, since it only applies to one of the years, and it's a duplicate of that value.

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values (data .reduce (
  (a, {location, postcode, price, year}) => 
    ({
      ...a, 
      [postcode]: ({...(a[postcode] || {location, postcode}), year: {...(a[postcode] && a[postcode].year || {}), [year]: price}
      })
    }), 
  {}
))

const data = [{"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "91449", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50460", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "93285", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "64958", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "71307", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "81671", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Camden", "postcode": "NW1 8QL", "price": "120933", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Croydon", "postcode": "CR2 7PA", "price": "69158", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Ealing", "postcode": "W13 0JX", "price": "79886", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Enfield", "postcode": "EN2 7AA", "price": "72515", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Greenwich", "postcode": "SE9 1DU", "price": "62300", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hackney", "postcode": "E8 1FD", "price": "61297", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hammersmith & Fulham", "postcode": "W6 8AB", "price": "124903", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Haringey", "postcode": "N8 9DJ", "price": "76288", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Harrow", "postcode": "HA3 5AG", "price": "84770", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Havering", "postcode": "RM12 6PL", "price": "68000", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hillingdon", "postcode": "UB8 1JZ", "price": "73835", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hounslow", "postcode": "TW3 2DL", "price": "72232", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Islington", "postcode": "N5 1RA", "price": "92516", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kensington & Chelsea", "postcode": "W8 5SA", "price": "182695", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kingston upon Thames", "postcode": "KT5 9NX", "price": "80876", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lambeth", "postcode": "SW9 8HE", "price": "67771", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lewisham", "postcode": "SE6 4RE", "price": "60491", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Merton", "postcode": "SW20 9JT", "price": "82071", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Newham", "postcode": "E13 9AP", "price": "53539", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Redbridge", "postcode": "IG6 1NA", "price": "72190", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Richmond upon Thames", "postcode": "TW9 1EZ", "price": "109326", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Southwark", "postcode": "SE1 5AA", "price": "67885", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Sutton", "postcode": "SM1 1JA", "price": "71537", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Tower Hamlets", "postcode": "E14 7JE", "price": "59865", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Waltham Forest", "postcode": "E17 7LP", "price": "61319", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Wandsworth", "postcode": "SW12 8PB", "price": "88559", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Westminster", "postcode": "SW1H 0BB", "price": "133025,", "year": "95"}, {"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "108999", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50828", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "91111", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "63996", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "72806", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "82210", "year": "96"}]

console .log (
  transform (data)
)
```

I do prefer when I can to program with expressions rather than statements, but that may have gone overboard here; it might be cleaner to use some temporary variables.

Note that this version does not include all years in the results, only the ones in the input.  If you want to include all the years as empty strings if not found, I would use some helper functions, although they could obviously be inlined if necessary:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [...Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => lo + i)
const makeYears = (start, end) => 
  range (start, end).reduce ((a, y) => ({...a, [('' + y).slice(-2)]: ''}))

const transform = (data, start, end) => Object .values (data .reduce (
  (a, {location, postcode, price, year}) => 
    ({
      ...a, 
      [postcode]: ({
        ... (a [postcode] || {location, postcode}), 
        year: {... ( a [postcode] && a [postcode] .year || makeYears (start, end)), [year]: price}
      })
    }), 
  {}
))

const data = [{"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "91449", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50460", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "93285", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "64958", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "71307", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "81671", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Camden", "postcode": "NW1 8QL", "price": "120933", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Croydon", "postcode": "CR2 7PA", "price": "69158", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Ealing", "postcode": "W13 0JX", "price": "79886", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Enfield", "postcode": "EN2 7AA", "price": "72515", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Greenwich", "postcode": "SE9 1DU", "price": "62300", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hackney", "postcode": "E8 1FD", "price": "61297", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hammersmith & Fulham", "postcode": "W6 8AB", "price": "124903", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Haringey", "postcode": "N8 9DJ", "price": "76288", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Harrow", "postcode": "HA3 5AG", "price": "84770", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Havering", "postcode": "RM12 6PL", "price": "68000", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hillingdon", "postcode": "UB8 1JZ", "price": "73835", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Hounslow", "postcode": "TW3 2DL", "price": "72232", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Islington", "postcode": "N5 1RA", "price": "92516", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kensington & Chelsea", "postcode": "W8 5SA", "price": "182695", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Kingston upon Thames", "postcode": "KT5 9NX", "price": "80876", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lambeth", "postcode": "SW9 8HE", "price": "67771", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Lewisham", "postcode": "SE6 4RE", "price": "60491", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Merton", "postcode": "SW20 9JT", "price": "82071", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Newham", "postcode": "E13 9AP", "price": "53539", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Redbridge", "postcode": "IG6 1NA", "price": "72190", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Richmond upon Thames", "postcode": "TW9 1EZ", "price": "109326", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Southwark", "postcode": "SE1 5AA", "price": "67885", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Sutton", "postcode": "SM1 1JA", "price": "71537", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Tower Hamlets", "postcode": "E14 7JE", "price": "59865", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Waltham Forest", "postcode": "E17 7LP", "price": "61319", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Wandsworth", "postcode": "SW12 8PB", "price": "88559", "year": "95"}, {"location": "Westminster", "postcode": "SW1H 0BB", "price": "133025", "year": "95"}, {"location": "City of London", "postcode": "EC1A 7BE", "price": "108999", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barking & Dagenham", "postcode": "RM9 4TP", "price": "50828", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Barnet", "postcode": "EN5 5RP", "price": "91111", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bexley", "postcode": "DA16 3DN", "price": "63996", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Brent", "postcode": "HA9 9AA", "price": "72806", "year": "96"}, {"location": "Bromley", "postcode": "BR1 3NN", "price": "82210", "year": "96"}]

console .log (
  transform (data, 1995, 2019)
)
```

---

### Update

I was called out in the comments (quite appropriately!) for posting code too complex for the question.  To make amends, I'm going to post a series of edits from what I think of as beginner code through intermediate to what I prefer these days.  All of these have the API of my first example: they build the result object from scratch, and don't try to use the secondary object.  They also only include the years that are found, not any missing ones.

First is a version I might expect from a competent beginner:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  const allItems = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data [i]
    let location = allItems [item.postcode]
    if (!location) {
      location = {
        location: item .location,
        postcode: item .postcode,
        years: {}
      }
    }
    location.years [item .year] = item .price;
    allItems [item .postcode] = location
  }
  return Object .values (allItems)
}
```

One of the first lessons I try to teach beginners looking to become intermediate developers is to replace `for` loops with more meaningful constructs.  I find that `map`, `filter`, `find`, and `reduce` cover at least 95% of the loops we see.  I want my team to think about them first, and to rarely resort to `for`.

So this is the first change I would expect to the function:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  const temp = data .reduce (
    (allItems, item) => {
      let location = allItems [item .postcode]
      if (!location) {
        location = {
          location: item .location,
          postcode: item .postcode,
          years: {}
        }
      }
      location .years [item .year] = item .price;
      allItems [item .postcode] = location
      return allItems
    },
    {}
  )
  return Object .values (temp)
}
```

On the premise that DRY is usually a good idea, I don't like all those repetitions of `item` in that code.  It would be nice to gather `item`'s parts up front.  ES6 offers a useful syntax for that. This version looks cleaner to me:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  const temp = data .reduce (
    (allItems, item) => {
      const {postcode, location, year, price} = item
      let newLocation = allItems [postcode]
      if (!newLocation) {
        newLocation = {
          location: location,
          postcode: postcode,
          years: {}
        }
      }
      newLocation.years [year] = price;
      allItems [postcode] = newLocation
      return allItems
    },
    {}
  )
  return Object .values (temp)
}
```

But then modern parameter handling means that we don't have to even define the `items` variable.  We can move it into the parameter to the `reduce` callback.  While this is a minor tweak, I think it often helps to remove unneeded variables:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  const temp = data .reduce (
    (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
      let newLocation = allItems [postcode]
      if (!newLocation) {
        newLocation = {
          location: location,
          postcode: postcode,
          years: {}
        }
      }
      newLocation.years [year] = price;
      allItems [postcode] = newLocation
      return allItems
    },
    {}
  )
  return Object .values (temp)
}
```

The assignment and then possible reassignment of `newLocation` might be fine in a language like Java, but JS offers a nice syntax for handling this.  We can use `a = b || c` rather than `a = b; if (!a) {a = c}`.  That seems much cleaner:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  const temp = data .reduce (
    (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
      let newLocation = allItems [postcode] || {
        location: location,
        postcode: postcode,
        years: {}
      }
      newLocation.years [year] = price;
      allItems [postcode] = newLocation
      return allItems
    },
    {}
  )
  return Object .values (temp)
}
```

There's another variable that definitely isn't adding anything: `temp`.  And it's quite easy to get rid of it without making anything more complex:

```js
const transform = (data) => {
  return Object .values ( data .reduce (
    (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
      let newLocation = allItems [postcode] || {
        location: location,
        postcode: postcode,
        years: {}
      }
      newLocation.years [year] = price;
      allItems [postcode] = newLocation
      return allItems
    },
    {}
  ))
}
```

An arrow function with a body that is just `return <someExpression>` can be simplified to simply return that expression.  That reduces the visual noise without affecting readability.  I do not insist on this from my intermediate developers, but I appreciate it when then do so:

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
    let newLocation = allItems [postcode] || {
      location: location,
      postcode: postcode,
      years: {}
    }
    newLocation.years [year] = price;
    allItems [postcode] = newLocation
    return allItems
  },
  {}
))
```

At this point, we have code that I will happily accept from an intermediate developer.  The repetition is gone, and the temporary variable remaining (`newLocation`) is much harder to eliminate than the ones we've removed so far.  This is readable and speaks pretty directly to the problem.

There is not necessarily any reason to move on from here.  But I'll do so anyway, because I think that more advanced development techniques also have something to offer.

I'm a strong advocate of doing functional programming in JS.  JS is a multi-paradigm language that allows procedural, object-oriented, or functional code.  Note that it is not the best language for any of those paradigms, but it handles all of them reasonably.  I try to push for more functional code.  That means a few things: clearly it means that we write many functions.  But it also means that we avoid side-effects in as much of our system as we can and, most relevant here, it means that we treat data as immutable.

In this most recent incarnation, we are still mutating two variables: `newLocation.years[year] = price` and `allItems[postcode] = newLocation`.  The next steps are aimed at eliminating that mutation.  First we remove the mutation of `allItems` by returning a new object in each invocation of the `reduce` callback:

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
    let newLocation = allItems [postcode] || {
      location: location,
      postcode: postcode,
      years: {}
    }
    newLocation.years[year] = price;
    return {...allItems, [postcode]: newLocation}
  },
  {}
))
```

(There is a good argument to be made against this style [for performance reasons](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).  I always fall on the side of writing the best code I can [without being too stupid about performance], testing the app, and fixing only those performance issues that actually matter to my users, always starting with the ones that hurt the most.  So I write this style, recognizing that here some mutation might eventually be necessary to get my system to the performance I would want.)

We can repeat this for the inner item:

```
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
    let newLocation = allItems[postcode] || {
      location: location,
      postcode: postcode,
    }
    return {
      ...allItems, 
      [postcode]: {...newLocation, years: {...newLocation .years, [year]: price}}
    }
  },
  {}
))
```

Now it's time for some simplification.  I didn't notice this when I wrote my original version in my answer, but my result doesn't need the `location` or `postcode` from `newLocation`; I could use those directly, and create a smaller temporary object of `years`:

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
    let years = allItems [postcode] && allItems [postcode] .years
    return {
      ...allItems, 
      [postcode]: {location, postcode, years: {...years, [year]: price}}
    }
  },
  {}
))
```

Then I can simply inline that `years` temporary variable:

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => {
    return {
      ...allItems, 
      [postcode]: {location, postcode, years: {
        ...(allItems [postcode] && allItems [postcode] .years), 
        [year]: price
      }}
    }
  },
  {}
))
```

And finally, I again have an arrow function whose body consists of a single `return` statement, so we can simplify that:

```js
const transform = (data) => Object .values ( data .reduce (
  (allItems, {postcode, location, year, price}) => ({
    ...allItems, 
    [postcode]: {location, postcode, years: {
      ...(allItems [postcode] && allItems [postcode] .years), 
      [year]: price
    }}
  }),
  {}
))
```

(Still to do: find the right name for `allItems`.  For generic code, I tend to write `acc` for "accumulator" or often just `a`.  But this is for a specific use case, and there should be a useful name for the accumulating object.  I don't know what the data represents, exactly.  Perhaps the term is `locations` or something similar.  Whatever it should be, my final version would include that change as well.)

This isn't identical to my original post; it's actually a bit of an improvement on that.  But it's built on similar ideas.  Getting code like this from one of my team makes me very happy, even with the caveat that I might have to change it by introducing some mutation if tests show the performance is not good enough.

An interesting feature of this version is that this function is built entirely out of expressions, not statements. Programs consisting of expressions allow you to reason about their behavior much more easily.  I wouldn't expect this code from an intermediate developer, never mind a junior one.  And there are plenty of experienced senior developers who would write it differently.  If I received this from a developer, however, I would assume that developer is senior-level.

---

Whew, that was quite a ride.  I hope someone finds it interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do appreciate it. For me this looks far too complicated and it's very difficult for me to read. 

it might make sense to you, but not to me.

Cheers

Comment: I think this answer is way too complicated for a "language-understanding" question. OP is more interested in understanding HOW the answer works than the answer itself.

Comment: @davidmitten: Added a long explanation of the code, as a series of transformations.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a match:

Say for example: Year 95, store the year and a price in a NewObject. Then while searching for the year in the second data set try to use year to search I hope that is what you have done recently.

Now use this syntax in the loop while mapping data for second object

> SecondObject.Year.k = NewObject.price

```
if (k === j.year) {

  var compiledData = compiledData.map( function (compiledData))
  {
     if(k === DataCompiled.year)
           DataCompiled.year.k = j.price
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help if I identify which data set is which -_-
Ill edit the question to show this too.

data = 1st set
compiledData = 2nd set

Comment: Checkout the final solution hope this helps or gives you an idea on what has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is first making a dictionary of Price Data let's call it `referenceData`.

```
var dict = {};
   referenceData.forEach(_=> {
         if(!dict[_.year]) {
        dict[_.year] = []; 
     }
     dict[_.year].push(_)
    })
```

Now check every year of data with corresponding year from the dictionary and find the price.

```
compiledData.forEach(_=> {
    var year = {};
    var years = Object.keys(_.year);
    years.forEach(y => {
        var priceData = dict[y];
        if(priceData) {
            var foundData = priceData.find(d => d.location === _.location || d.postcode === _.postcode);
            if(!foundData) year[y] = foundData.price;
        }
    })
    _.year = year;
})
```

If you have to use this kind of data manipulation a lot, it is strongly recommended to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)